# How to make Shapes.HasTitle find all titles in presentation (VBA, .ppt)?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to extract all titles from a presentation to an excel spreadsheet with its page index. My code works relatively well overall but is not picking up every title unfortunately.

I basically used the `Shapes.HasTitle` method, my code is a bit sloppy (looping once to set the size of the array that will be used, then to populate the array) but is relatively straight forward otherwise.

```
Dim sld As Slide
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim table As Range
Dim bottomLeft As Range
Dim titlesNPages() As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
myFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="PowerPoint Files,*.ppt*;*.pptx*")
If myFileName <> False Then
    Set ppt = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(myFileName)
End If

'Setting array to the right size (# of shapes with title)
For Each sld In ppt.slides
    With sld
        If .Shapes.HasTitle Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End With
Next sld
ReDim titlesNPages(1 To 2, 1 To i)

i = 0

'Populating array
For Each sld In ppt.slides
    With sld
        If .Shapes.HasTitle Then
        i = i + 1
            titlesNPages(1, i) = .SlideIndex 'Page index
            titlesNPages(2, i) = .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'Title
        End If
    End With
Next sld

With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set bottomLeft = .Range("B3").Offset(UBound(titlesNPages, 2) - 1, 1)
    Set table = .Range("B3:" & bottomLeft.Address)
    table.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(titlesNPages)
End With
End Sub
```

The main issue is that Shapes.HasTitle doesn't seem to be picking up on all shapes that are titles nor on titles that were produced in a ppt that was in a language other than English.
Any ideas to get this to work a bit better? It is currently getting close to 70% of titles (then I'll need to figure out how to deal with the textboxes that are actually titles)

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the titles in a normal presentation. Each shape is checked for whether it has text and is a placeholder. If both are true it checks for the title placeholder format:

```
Sub GetTitles()
  Dim oSlide As Slide, oShape As Shape
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      If oShape.Type = msoPlaceholder And oShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
        If oShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderTitle Or _
        oShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderCenterTitle Then
          MsgBox oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        End If
      End If
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

If you have decks where users have repurposed titles for text boxes, or vice versa, you may have to do more checking based on the text size used and to see if the shape position is in the right area for a title.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That definitely looks promising. Could you give me a quick pointer on how one could check for text size and shape position?

Comment: For position: If oShape.Left > 36 And oShape.Left < 108 And oShape.Top > 36 And oShape.Top < 108 Then

For text size: If oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size > 36 Then

Comment: Thank you for your help!